# Decode Swift Dictionary Json

Tags: ios, json, dictionary

I m having a problem decoding the following json because I have and array of dictionaries of different data types, and Any does not support codable?

What can I change in the model to make it work?
Thank you.

Here is the json

```
 "alerts":[
  {
     "id":"https://api.weather.gov/alerts/urn:oid:2.49.0.1.840.0.eae34c2b3a065ca71d8746f3c67123c93a12257d.002.1",
     "areaDescription":"Ashland, OH; Knox, OH; Richland, OH",
     "dateSent":1680365400,
     "dateEffective":1680365400,
     "dateOnset":1680365400,
     "dateExpires":1680366600,
     "dateEnds":1680366600,
     "severity":"Severe",
     "certainty":"Observed",
     "urgency":"Immediate",
     "senderName":"NWS Cleveland OH",
     "description":"At 1208 PM EDT, severe thunderstorms were located along a line extending from near Nashville to 7 miles east of Utica, moving east at 60 mph.\n\nHAZARD...60 mph wind gusts.\n\nSOURCE...Radar indicated.\n\nIMPACT...Expect damage to trees and power lines.\n\nLocations impacted include... Mansfield, Mount Vernon, Lexington, Loudonville, Fredericktown, Gambier, Utica, Bellville, Centerburg, Danville, Waterford, Butler, Perrysville, Lucas, Martinsburg, Gann, North Liberty and Bladensburg.",
     "instruction":"For your protection move to an interior room on the lowest floor of a building.",
     "response":"Shelter",
     "event":"Severe Thunderstorm Warning",
     "headline":"Severe Thunderstorm Warning issued April 1 at 12:10PM EDT until April 1 at 12:30PM EDT by NWS Cleveland OH",
     "nwsHeadline":[
        "A SEVERE THUNDERSTORM WARNING REMAINS IN EFFECT UNTIL 1230 PM EDT FOR SOUTHERN RICHLAND...SOUTHEASTERN ASHLAND AND KNOX COUNTIES"
     ],
     "polygon":[
        [
           40.24,
           -82.48
        ],
        [
           40.27,
           -82.48
        ],
        [
           40.28,
           -82.74000000000001
        ],
        [
           40.35,
           -82.75000000000001
        ],
        [
           40.35,
           -82.65000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.550000000000004,
           -82.64000000000001
        ],
        [
           40.550000000000004,
           -82.62000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.67,
           -82.65000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.67,
           -82.62000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.71,
           -82.62000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.72,
           -82.73000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.729999899999996,
           -82.73000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.709999999999994,
           -82.13000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.669999999999995,
           -82.13000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.669999999999995,
           -82.22000000000003
        ],
        [
           40.56999999999999,
           -82.22000000000003
        ],
        [
           40.56999999999999,
           -82.18000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.239999999999995,
           -82.20000000000002
        ],
        [
           40.24,
           -82.48
        ]
     ],
     "multiPolygon":[
        [
           [
              40.24,
              -82.48
           ],
           [
              40.27,
              -82.48
           ],
           [
              40.28,
              -82.74000000000001
           ],
           [
              40.35,
              -82.75000000000001
           ],
           [
              40.35,
              -82.65000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.550000000000004,
              -82.64000000000001
           ],
           [
              40.550000000000004,
              -82.62000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.67,
              -82.65000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.67,
              -82.62000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.71,
              -82.62000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.72,
              -82.73000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.729999899999996,
              -82.73000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.709999999999994,
              -82.13000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.669999999999995,
              -82.13000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.669999999999995,
              -82.22000000000003
           ],
           [
              40.56999999999999,
              -82.22000000000003
           ],
           [
              40.56999999999999,
              -82.18000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.239999999999995,
              -82.20000000000002
           ],
           [
              40.24,
              -82.48
           ]
        ]
     ],
     "affectedZoneIDs":[
        {
           "type":"county",
           "id":"OHC005"
        },
        {
           "type":"county",
           "id":"OHC083"
        },
        {
           "type":"county",
           "id":"OHC139"
        }
     ],
     "messageType":"update"
  },
{,
```

Here is what I have now:

```
   func getWeatherAlerts() -> AnyPublisher<Alerts, Error> {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.alltheapps.org/weather/v3/allActiveAlerts?apiKey=da230328") else {
        return Fail(error: CustomError.invalidUrl).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    return URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        .catch { error in
            return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }.map( {$0.data})
        .decode(type: Alerts.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

and the mapping

```
struct Alerts: Decodable {
let alerts: [[String:String]]
```

}

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case alertTitle = "event"
case startDateAlert = "dateOnset"
case endDateAlert = "dateEnds"
case sourceOfAlert = "senderName"
```

}

```
struct WeatherAlertsModel:Decodable {
var alertTitle:String
var startDateAlert:Date
var endDateAlert:Date
var sourceOfAlert:String
var severity:String
var certainty:String
var urgency:String
var description:String
var affectedZoneIDs:[String]
```

}

It give me an error on parsing because I have [String:String], and the json has also [String:Int] or [String:Date]

Comment: According to the JSON the type of `Alerts` is `[WeatherAlertsModel]`. And the type of `affectedZoneIDs` is  `[ZoneID]` representing this struct  `struct ZoneID: Decodable { let type, id: String }`

Comment: The JSON you've actually posted isn't valid, but assuming the errors are small typos, this isn't an array of dictionaries of different data types. There's just one record, and it has a pretty clear data type. Drop it into app.quicktype.io and it'll spit out the struct. If this really is an array of different types that you didn't post here, search for "[swift] json heterogeneous" and you'll find many versions of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+json+heterogeneous

Answer (score 0):

You could use a struct like this :

```
struct WeatherALaertsModel: Codable {
    struct Alert: Codable, Identifiable {
        var id: String
        var areaDescription: String
        var description: String
        // add any other needed record
        
        typealias Point = [Double]
        typealias Polygon = [Point]
        typealias MultiPolygon = [Polygon]
        var polygon: Polygon
        
        var multiPolygon: MultiPolygon
        
        struct ZoneId: Codable, Identifiable {
            var type: String
            var id: String
        }
        
        var affectedZoneIDs: [ZoneId]
        var messageType: String
    }
    let alerts: [Alert]
}

// Assuming you get the json in a Data var named "data"
let weatherModel = try decoder.decode(WeatherALaertsModel.self, from: data)
```